# Mobile automation on ios using calabash

Tags: calabash-ios

Is rebuilding of ipa mandatory while working on iOS automation using calabash?

If it is mandatory then how can it be run on Xamarin Test cloud/testmunk?

Can any one elaborate on this? I'm starting from scratch. But no proper site for set up or execution.

I need assistance on the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Is rebuilding of ipa mandatory

Calabash iOS requires that you app be linked with the calabash.framework.

> how can it be run on Xamarin Test Cloud

You submit an ipa that has been linked with the calabash.framework.

> no proper site for set up or execution

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Tutorial%3A-How-to-add-Calabash-to-Xcode